# The function space $C^k[a,b]$ and $C^{k+1}[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $C^k[a,b]$ be the space of functions defined over [a,b] and are differentiable $k$ times and the $k$-th derivative is also continuous. Then $C^k[a,b]$ is a $\mathbb R$ vector space (or $\mathbb C$ vector space if we consider the complex valued function). And it is obvious that $C^{k+1}[a,b]\subsetneq C^k[a,b]$.

My question is what is the dimension of the quotient space $C^k[a,b]/C^{k+1}[a,b]$? Is it an infinite vector space? If so, can we find a basis about the space?

Comment: Consider case $k=0$, take $f(x)=|x|$ in $C[-1,1]$.

Comment: Or better: $f(x)= |x-t|$ for some parameter $t\in (-1,1)$.